# Listar las cuentas de AWS incluyendo sus tags

Tags: aws

Estoy intentando listar todas las cuentas de AWS junto con sus etiquetas asignadas. El comando que estoy utilizando es:

`aws organizations list-tags-for-resource —resource-id “ACCID”`

Esto me devuelve el resultado que busco, pero no puedo añadir más de un “ACCOUNT ID” por lo que si quiero obtener el resultado de todas las cuentas, tengo que ir ejecutando el comando por cada cuenta.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer este listado de cuentas?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta todas las veces que quieras usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).